# C++ behavior unexpected of Set of class objects

Tags: c++, oop

For example, take a std::set of std::pair<int,int>, if you insert 2 pairs, {1,1} and {1,2}, both of them will be inserted in the set, however when i implemented a pair class, this behaviour is not seen. Only one of them gets inserted in the set. Please explain why?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class PAIR {
public:
    int x, y;
    bool operator<(const PAIR& p) const { return x < p.x; }
};

int main() {
    set<PAIR> s;
    s.insert({ 1,1 });
    s.insert({ 1,2 });
    cout << s.size();
}
```

The output comes out to be 1, unlike i expected

Comment: Your pair class says that {1,1} and {1,2} are the same. Is it supposed to do that? Because they're the same, you can only have one.

Comment: @user253751, no it's not supposed to do that.

Comment: Then you need to fix your `operator<` inside your custom `PAIR` in order to make it consider the `y` field too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set can only hold unique values.  It uses operator< to determine uniqueness.

For two items *a* and *b*, if `(!(a<b) && !(b<a))` then they are considered equivalent.

Your operator< only considers the *x* member of your pair, so the *y* member is completely ignored for purposes of your set.

Comment: the are considered "equivalent", `a == b` (equality) can have different result

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` uses `operator<` for ordering *and* equivalence (it assumes equivalence when `a<b` and `a>b` are both `false`).

So with an `operator<` like `x < p.x` you're saying that only `x` is participating in comparison and `y` doesn't matter.

To use both `x` and `y`, the comparison should look more like:

```
    bool operator<(const PAIR& p) const {
        return std::tie(x, y) < std::tie(p.x, p.y);
    }
```